# How to make a dropdown to select proper selected item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a dropdown like below.

```
<select name="slt">
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
 <option value="3">Three +</option>
</select>
```

If I select the option Three + , after some page refresh the selected option became Three because Three and Three + has same value. How to avoid this and make the selected item as Three + after page refresh?
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the browser will automatically retain the value. If the value is a duplicate it will pick the first one it finds in the list.

To stop this behaviour, you need to give the `Three+` option a unique `value`, for example:

```
<option value="3+">Three +</option>
```

---

If you cannot change the HTML at all, you will need to store the selected index of the element in localStorage, or a cookie, and set it again on load:

```
// set onchange
$('select').change(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('sltIndex', $(this).prop("selectedIndex"));
});

// get onload
$(this).prop("selectedIndex", localStorage.getItem('sltIndex') || 0)
```

The pattern is the same for using a cookie, although the code would need amending.

Comment: But my data is like that only. I cant change it.